# Replacing width with max-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with 6 columns that are dynamic (php), which means that I can't just change the html.

I have:

```
.col-sw-6 {
    width: 16.6666%;
}
```

and I need to replace `width` with `max-width`. I already tried:

```
.main-menu .col-sw-6 {
    width: 16.6666%;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

but it is not working. Any idea on how to do this if possible involving only CSS?

Comment: and your html is?

Comment: Why do you need to replace width with max-width?

Comment: This is a Magento site with a huge "mega menu". The issue was that the columns looked too crowded. I just found down somewhere in the menu a div with a fixed width so I applied width:100% and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem in my opinion is that you should not change this in css only.

You are simply doing it wrong, first indicator is that you are trying to set the width to 6 column wide element to something different.

In reality you should change the class name based on your PHP output,
so when PHP return 3 items, you should have col-md-4, when output is 4 items, it should be col-md-3 etc.

This way you don't need to: 
1. Fight with some stupid css rules
2. Override your grid system ( which is in general wrong idea ).

So instead of handling width in css only, update the code to change the html representation with correct class names based on number of navigation items and then each class will have proper css width setup.

If you always have 6 columns, what makes your need to change the width?
If not, ( what i assume as you mentioned its dynamic ), then what i wrote makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `.col-sw-6` class *contains* a width setting definition. If you want to override that, remove that class from your div tag.